# Trying to automatically insert ZonedDateTime into h2 database when inserting/creating a record

Tags: java, hibernate, rest, h2, zoneddatetime

I am working on a ticketingSystem, and my task now is to, whenever a ticket is created, automatically assign to it the date and time it got created. I am doing so by adding the ZonedDateTime.now() in the Ticket Date setter function, as well as in the TicketDto class.

I am assuming it could be one of these 2 problems :

1. I am creating a new ticket by manually adding a record to the h2 database and leaving the Date field empty, and expecting it to be filled with ZonedDateTime.now() value, when it's not
2. The date column in the table is of type Timestamp, which could be causing this problem as well, but I am not sure

Any small tips would be very helpful and very much appreciated!
Thanks in advance

Comment: [The docs say](http://h2database.com/html/datatypes.html#timestamp_with_time_zone_type): *This data type holds the local date and time without time zone information. It cannot distinguish timestamps near transitions from DST to normal time. For absolute timestamps use the TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE data type instead.

See also timestamp literal grammar.

In JDBC this data type is mapped to java.sql.Timestamp (java.util.Date may be used too). java.time.LocalDateTime is also supported and recommended.* Wouldn't it be an idea to store the time zone of the person who bought the ticket?

Comment: it would be an idea, but I want the timezone to depend on the person who's seeing the ticket rather than who created it, since, let's say, I open a ticket to file a bug, at 9am in Canada, which means around 3pm in London. So the person in London should see 3pm, and not 9am. Does that make sense? @g00se

Comment: Well yes, but *storing* the timezone and its use are two entirely different things. It's perfectly possible for the viewer to see any timezone they want